# Duplicate column and add an automatic extension with mySQL. How?

Tags: mysql

I have two columns with mySQL:

"part_no"

"pdf_link"

I need the "pdf_link" column to automatically grab/duplicate the "part_no" value and add a .pdf extension on the end.

For example:  If part_no = 00-12345-998, then pdf_link = 00-12345-998.pdf

I need this to happen every time I insert.

[image]

I appreciate the help.

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achive this effect by using triggers I think.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_pdf AFTER INSERT ON MY_TABLE SET @pdf_link = concat(@part_no,'.pdf')
```

Comment: Ok... Where would I place this triggger in myPHP admin?

Comment: you are welcome, although I couldn't check whether syntax is correct. If it is working, then it is good.

Answer (score 0):

Why store this extra computed information in the database? You can do this in the query when you pull it out, or, if needed, you could make a view that does it only as-needed.

Example pseudo query (my brain hurts right now, so this is only an example):

```
select concat(`part_no`, ".pdf") as `pdf_link` from `parts`;
```

---

If you *really* need this, you could use a trigger to duplicate the data ans add the extra string.

Comment: Yes... I understand, but I wanted to know if its possible and how.